# Is N1 and N2 and any N speed the revolutions per second for the rotor blades of compressors?

Tags: compressor

For example the Airbus A350 has three N speeds I think is called Nucelle speed and N1 is for the fan or LP compressor, N2 is for the IP compressor and N3 is for the HP compressor. Even on the Airbus A320 with N1 is the L.P. compressor and N2 is the HP compressor. But anyways is the N speeds how many revolution per second it's doing or What?